# TCL, replacing strings in a textfile

Tags: string, file, replace, tcl, text-files

lets say I open a file, then parsed it into lines. Then I use a loop:

```
foreach line $lines {}
```

e.g., if the file contained the following string:

```
XYDATA, NAME1
```

I want to put `ACC_` after the `XYDATA` to get `ACC_NAME1`
and if the file contains more than one strings with `XYDATA`, put `VEL_`, `DSP_` and `Prs_` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`textutil::split`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_split.html) package from [tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/index.html), and the ability of [`foreach`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm) to iterate over multiple lists simultaneously

```
package require textutil::split

set line {XYDATA, foo, bar, baz, qux}
set prefixes {ACC_ VEL_ DSP_ Prs_}

set fields [textutil::split::splitx $line {, }]
set new [list]

if {[lindex $fields 0] eq "XYDATA"} {
    lappend new [lindex $fields 0]
    foreach prefix $prefixes field [lrange $fields 1 end] {
        lappend new $prefix$field
    }
}
puts [join $new ", "]
```

```
XYDATA, ACC_foo, VEL_bar, DSP_baz, Prs_qux
```

---

alternately, use a single regsub call that generates some code

```
set code [regsub -all {(, )([^,]+)} $line {\1[lindex $prefixes [incr counter]]\2}]
set counter -1
puts [subst $code]
```

Comment: Regular `split` would work too, leaving the commas at the end of the fields.

Comment: I was thinking there might be additional spaces in the fields.